# What shall I mention for the 'name' attribute ? Why this validation error?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, associations, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to make a `one-to-one` relation between `Country` class and `PM` class.This is the `xml mapping` I tried to 
make.But there is something wrong with the `xml` as the error says.

***`Attribute "name" is required and must be specified for element type "one-to-one".`***

I do not understand this. What shall I mention for the `name` attribute ? I mentioned the class with which I am trying to 
make a one-to-one relation.

```
<class name="pojo.Country" table="country">
      <id name="c_id">
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="name_c" />
      <one-to-one class="pojo.PM" />
</class>

<class name="pojo.PM" table="pm">
      <id name="c_id">
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="name_pm" />
</class>
```

There are two tables named `pm` and `country`. The relation I am trying to make is that *one country can have one PM and PM can belong to one country.*

Answer (score 0):

You should specify to which attribute you're making this relationship.
For example for country:

country_id, country_name, country_PM (which has pm_ids in it)

Try this:

```
<class name="pojo.Country" table="country">
  <id name="c_id">
      <generator class="increment" />
  </id>
  <property name="name_c" />
  <one-to-one class="pojo.PM" name="pm_id" foreign_key="c_id"/>
</class>
```

if that doesn't work. Try `property-ref` instead of `foreign-key` attribute

Comment: If I give a name of the attribute, I get an error as  it searches for that attribute in the same class i.e `Country` but not inside `PM`. What do I do now ?

Comment: please see my edited answer: you should define column attribute to specify where to link

Comment: where to add the `column` attribute ? `one-to-one` tag doesn't accept the `column` attribute ?

Comment: found it in docs. please refer here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone